# What is your recommended Banner/Slider module for D7?

Tags: 7

I am searching for module that create banner/slider effect for D7.

Have a check on this page: 
http://drupal.org/node/418616

Mostly not yet port to D7.

What are your recommend modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) a couple of times and it was quite easy to use. It's based on the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). The port to D7 is in alpha, so you might want to give it a go and contribute back to help the module reach a stable state.

That said, a module is not strictly necessary to do things like this. It's surprisingly easy to implement the (well documented) [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) yourself, directly from your theme. Just add the plugin and write about 10 lines of jQuery in a custom .js file.

Answer (score 1):

@marcavangend is mostly right.

There is one other to consider which is Drupal 7 only: [Rotating Banner](http://drupal.org/project/rotating_banner).

It may not match your exact needs, but it is quite nice.

> ### Features
>
> - Various transition effects (fade, wipe, etc)
> - Rich Editor where you can pick a background image and add headlines and text areas
> - Supports inline editing and drag and drop
> - Creates blocks, you can make a bunch of them
> - Can be a static size, or will grow to the size of your largest / smallest image or the size of the region you put it in automatically

Comment: It looks like it's not maintained anymore. I am choosing between Views Slideshow and Nivo Slider. Views Slideshow looks like it's more robust. Will post here after I've compared them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module.

> Nivo Slider provides an easy and eye-catching way to showcase featured content. Nivo Slider gives administrators three important tools:
>
> - A simple method of adding slides to the slideshow.
> - An administration interface to configure slideshow settings.
> - Simple slider positioning using the Drupal block system.